# Web Service: Cast or Convert Generated Objects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I'm running into an issue with casting a generated object from a Web service to a C# object I've created. This object is housed inside a common library that both the and server client have access to so I ideally I would like to use this instead of a generated object type.

So my question is, is it possible to do some sort of "casting" or conversion, and if so, what are the best approaches.

EDIT:
The problem I'm running into is that the casting is not working. Consuming the web service is not a problem.

**Code for web service:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public CommonLib.Models.User GetInfo()
    {
        return new CommonLib.Models.User()
        {
            Firstname = "John",
            Lastname = "Doe",
            UserID = 1,
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now

        };
    }
}
```

**Code to consume web service:**

```
WebService1SoapClient prox = new WebService1SoapClient();

object userInfo = prox.GetInfo();
CommonLib.Models.User two = (CommonLib.Models.User)userInfo;
```

**User object**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working in the code you posted? If GetInfo() returns an object, you are going to have to do the cast.

Comment: @LordTakkera Yes, the casting isn't working. I am able to consume the web service without problem.

Comment: Why does GetInfo() return a base object instead of a User object?

Comment: can you post the interface for the webservice? Or the WSDL?

Comment: Yes, if the serializer doesn't know about "User", the information is lost over the proxy. You need to make User a "Known Type" or just return a User object.

Comment: @1.618
The GetInfo() method returns a proxy (I believe is the term) object. I am able to access properties of the proxy class without problems. I instead want to use CommonLib.Models.User where I originally define the structure.

Comment: I updated the post with the code for the web service.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - If I use WCF, would I be able to do a simple cast and achieve the results I want?

Comment: If you use WCF, you won't need to cast -- the service can return the correct type of object directly.  You'd just put the [DataContract] attrib on the class in the interface for the webservice.

Comment: @1.618: that is not quite accurate. Neither WCF nor ASMX return objects. They all return XML. It's up to the client to deserialize the XML into an object.

Comment: Well they really just return bits, right?  And those are actually voltage pulses, really... How many layers of abstraction do you need to remove?  ;)

Comment: Hi all, a WCF does what I need it to do. Thanks all!

Comment: @1.618: they return bits in the form of XML, which is quite different from bits in the form of .NET objects. This level of abstraction is very useful when you want to permit the client or service to not be .NET applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by employing a WCF service and when I added a reference at the client, I simply checked the box to reuse reference assemblies like John Saunders suggested.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use "Add Service Reference", or "Configure Service Reference", choose "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies". You will then need to have the assembly which defines `CommonLib.Models.User` available both to the service and to the client.

To answer your comment, you are already using WCF on the client. You should simply never create any new ASMX services.

Comment: Yes, I have added a reference but casting is the problem. Let me try it quickly with a WCF service and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No, read what I said. Make sure that the client has a reference to the assembly that defines the types you want. Then, right-click your service reference and choose "Configure Service Reference". Be certain to check "Reuse types".

Comment: I got it working with a WCF service like you suggested. Thank you for your help!